# Strange Wi-Fi issue

Tags: wifi-configuration, speedtest

I, along with my other two flatmates, are experiencing problems with our ISP, which basically means, he sucks. The deal, we signed, says the bandwidth should be up to 100 mbps, but it regularly slows down to 10 mbps or even less. I have changed the channel to the least occupied and having the least neighbours. Yes, we do have an ISP-supplied router & modem. The cable (CAT-5) speed also sucks.

My question is: **Why do we have different Speedtest.net outputs with my friends?** I keep getting the lowest speed (e.g. *2 mbps* or even less with ping of around *20 ms*) and they usually have sth like *>20 mbps* but ping *>150 ms*. I am sitting in my room which is like four meters from the router (2 walls), and they have the router in their room.

**Do you have any other tips to customize the settings in order to obtain higher speed?** I've changed the DNS servers to Google's but that didn't helped at all. Thanks for the feedback.

P.S. Yes, we are fighting with our ISP legally too.

Comment: Two walls and the extra distance could make a big difference.

Comment: Damn. I thought that there might be something else I can fix. hmmm... So I think the hammer and the drill can fix the problem :D

Comment: It looks like  abad ISP, but I wonder if one of the computers on the network is sending out large amounts of traffic (P2P / Virus ?) Those 150ms pings while you are getting a 20ms ping look suspicious.   If a single computer connected to the router via Cat5 sucks then the problem is your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

In router settings try changing the frequency from 2.5 GHz to 5 GHz, also set the router to password restricted instead of open. It should resolve the problem.

Comment: Actually, you should also say that switching to 5 GHz has a good chance of making the problem worse since 5 GHz is less able to penetrate walls and is more affected by distance.

Comment: The router does not support 5 Ghz unfortunately. I presume the best way to deal with the problem would be to buy a new high-end router, but we cannot afford it. The router is password restricted, as well as the network.

Comment: You could then buy a WiFi range extender, a cheap one, Google them to find one.

Comment: @ronmaupin 5 GHz solve these kinds of problems, higher frequencies are able to penetrate walls more easily. And are affective for long distance.

Comment: You are completely incorrect. Higher frequencies do not penetrate walls as well as lower frequencies. That's the reason the sky is blue, and why the mobile phone carriers covet lower frequencies. Higher frequencies don't travel as far and can't penetrate objects as well as lower frequencies.

Comment: A newer iteration of Wi-Fi, IEEE 802.11ad, will operate at the much higher 60 Ghz, but, "_The 60 GHz signal cannot typically penetrate walls but can propagate off reflections from walls, ceilings, floors and objects using beamforming built into the WiGig system._" Higher frequencies cannot penetrate walls as well as lower frequencies, and the reflections can cause problems, too.

Comment: Sorry, but yes you are right, but that always seem to solve my issues I too have a router in a room and my sister always complained about it's speed. Her room was two room away and not in the line of sight too. I just increased the frequency and her speed increased greatly. We have a 100 Mbps connection, and she got 10-20 Mbps.

Comment: You experience may be because of interference in the much more crowded 2.4 GHz range, and there are a couple of other reasons, too. It is not wrong to try to solve the problem by switching to 5 GHz, but it should be noted that it may also cause worse performance because of the higher frequency range. I think you should edit your answer to explain this.